# How to obtain data from a memory address pointed by another pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address, pointer-to-pointer

I am working with GenICam library, one of the methods is described as follows:
[image]

I am using this method to get camera frames.
We must provide to `pBuffer` a pointer, the method will return to our pointer, the memory address where data is stored.

So, I want to obtain the data stored in that memory address, but doing it in this way:

```
char* image_data = nullptr; 
image_data = new char[1024];
status = gentl->DSGetBufferInfo(datastream_module_handle, new_buffer_event_data.BufferHandle, GenTL::BUFFER_INFO_BASE, &info_datatype, image_data, &info_datasize);
std::cout << **image_data << std::endl;
```

I am getting this error: error c2100 illegal indirection c++.

I tried to use an auxiliar pointer:

```
char* image_data = nullptr;
image_data = new char[1024];
char* p_image_data = nullptr;
p_image_data = new char[1024];
status = gentl ... (same method)
p_image_data = *image_data;
std::cout << *p_image_data << std::endl;
```

but i obtained the following error: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from char to char *.

How can I obtain the data stored in that memory address ?

Comment: There's no pointer-to-pointer in your code (nor there's any need for one).

Comment: You don't need `new` here, you can just declare `char image_data[1024]` (or `std::array<char, 1024> image_data` and pass `image_data.data()`)

Answer (score 3):

```
p_image_data = *image_data;
```

Should be

```
p_image_data = image_data;
```

They both have the same type (`char*`), so there's no need to dereference. By dereferencing `image_data`, you get a `char` again, and that can't be assigned to `p_image_data` (which is `char*`), hence the error.

Of course, now you're not copying the data, just setting the pointer. What you probably want instead is:

```
memcpy(p_image_data, image_data, 1024);
```

This copies the 1024 chars that `image_data` points to (after being modified by `DSGetBufferInfo`) to the 1024 bytes pointed to by `p_image_data`.